# How to position nodes around another node in TiKZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I'd like to position some nodes in TiKZ around a given node. I could do that manually, by setting each node position, but why not looking for an easier way that looks better?

I thought about using a path and stick the nodes to the path but I have no idea about doing this, and I also wonder: is the path the best solution?

An example would be the following where the base node is A (there is a node below it, but it's not a problem; also note that if you don't include the arrows in your answer, it's ok, I know that part):

[image]

My code so far has reached this stage (if you think some option in the code could be changed to make things easier or better, please let me know):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}


\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning} 
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, thin,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thin,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,}
}

\begin{document}

    \center\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm,
    terminal/.style={
    % The shape:
    rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    % The rest
    very thick,draw=black!50,
    top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
    font=\ttfamily}]

    \node (nodezero) [terminal] {another node below A};

    \node (a) [terminal, above=3em of nodezero] {A};

    \node (01) [terminal] {1};
    \node (02) [terminal] {2};        
    \node (03) [terminal] {3};
    \node (04) [terminal] {4};
    \node (05) [terminal] {5};
    \node (06) [terminal] {6};
    \node (07) [terminal] {7};
    \node (08) [terminal] {8};
    \node (09) [terminal] {9};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no `\center` macro, but a `center` environment. So either use `\begin{center}` .. `\end{center}` or `\center` .. `\endcenter`. I would recommend the first, which is the correct LaTeX version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may want to use the `trees` library in tikz, which in this situation would provide, up to me, a rather easy syntax. I made a small example for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,trees,arrows}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten <=0.5pt,
    main/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners, top color=blue!20, bottom color=white,
        minimum width=1cm},
    child/.style={draw,thick,rounded corners, top color=red!20, bottom color=white}]

    \tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling angle=22.5]

    \node[main] (a) {A} [counterclockwise from=0]
        child { node[child] {1}}
        child { node[child] {2}}
        child { node[child] {3}}
        child { node[child] {4}}
        child { node[child] {5}}
        child { node[child] {6}}
        child { node[child] {7}}
        child { node[child] {8}}
        child { node[child] {9}}
    ;

    \node[main] (ba) [below of=a] {belowA};

    \path 
    (ba) edge (a)
    ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives as result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! Where is the manual for this?

Comment: You can find the pgf and tikz manual here: http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf  
but I suggest you to take a look at this site http://www.texample.net/tikz/
which provides a lot of sound and complete examples.

Comment: Of course it's that! I kind of forgot it lol Thanks... :) I'm currently tweaking with it.

Comment: I try to use `\foreach \i in {1,...,9}  {child { node[child] {\i}}}`  but without success. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 12):

One way you can use here is the `\node (<name>) at (<coordinate>) {<text>};` syntax, where you can use the `calc` library to add a polar coordinate on the position of node `A`, i.e. `\node (1) at ($ (A) + (<angle>:<distance>) $) {1};`. For another ways see the `positioning` library in the manual.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    %Define standard arrow tip
    >=stealth',
    %Define style for boxes
    punkt/.style={
           rectangle,
           rounded corners,
           draw=black, thin,
           text width=6.5em,
           minimum height=2em,
           text centered},
    % Define arrow style
    pil/.style={
           ->,
           thin,
           shorten <=2pt,
           shorten >=2pt,}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm,
    terminal/.style={
    % The shape:
    rectangle,minimum size=6mm,rounded corners=3mm,
    % The rest
    very thick,draw=black!50,
    top color=white,bottom color=black!20,
    font=\ttfamily}]

    \node (nodezero) [terminal] {another node below A};

    \node (a) [terminal, above=3em of nodezero] {A};

    \node (01) at ($ (a) + (10:2cm) $) [terminal] {1};
    \node (02) at ($ (a) + (30:2cm) $) [terminal] {2};        
    \node (03) at ($ (a) + (50:2cm) $) [terminal] {3};
    \node (04) at ($ (a) + (70:2cm) $) [terminal] {4};
    \node (05) at ($ (a) + (90:2cm) $) [terminal] {5};
    \node (06) at ($ (a) + (110:2cm) $) [terminal] {6};
    \node (07) at ($ (a) + (130:2cm) $) [terminal] {7};
    \node (08) at ($ (a) + (150:2cm) $) [terminal] {8};
    \node (09) at ($ (a) + (170:2cm) $) [terminal] {9};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You can avoid the `calc` library and simplify the code with   `\begin{scope}[shift=(a)]
   \foreach \i in {1,...,9}  \node (0\i) at ({(\i-1)*20+10}:2cm) [terminal] {\i};  
  \end{scope}`

Comment: @Altermundus: Indeed! Very good idea.

Comment: Or `\path[every node/.style={terminal}] (a) foreach \i in {1,...,9} node (0\i) at +({\i-1)*20+10}:2cm) {\i};` (might have the `foreach` syntax incorrect).

Comment: Martin, thanks for your help, I accepted the other answer, but upvoted yours for the help. :)