# How to draw parallelepiped and cube with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

How can I draw these solid figures with LaTeX?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) -- ++(0,0,\cubez) -- cycle;
\draw[red,fill=yellow] (0,0,0) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) -- ++(\cubex,0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have used that code. How can I draw and write the quotes and dimensions?

Comment: There are several ways: [What is the easiest way to draw 3D cube with TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12020)

Comment: First select package (from flags I conclude, that you think about TikZ). Than instead draw ba hand just code movement: `\draw (coordinate 1) |- (coordinate 2) |- (coordinate 1);` if you like to have filled with some color, say `\draw[fill=green!30] (...) ...` etc.

Comment: thank you very much! And if I want to draw the quotes?

Comment: I've seen a question with this image before...

Comment: @Alenanno I hate that. Such a waste of time duplicating other people's efforts. Even worse is if I find I answered it the first time as well.

Comment: Should have checked the linked question, I guess. Not that this image is there, but because the OP has just lifted the code above from there (sans attribution, naturally).

Comment: @cfr the question is linked? Can't see it on mobile.

Comment: @Alenanno Not the one you mentioned, no.

Answer (score 27):

You can annotate the diagram in various ways. Here's one approach.

`coordinate`s are placed when constructing the cuboid. These are then used in a later path as starting points. Further coordinates are placed offset from the originals (a little below, a little left, a little right...) which are then used to draw the lines. Drawing these with the `edge` operation makes it possible to add arrow tips for the start and end of each line without using separate paths, and the `quotes` library is then used to label these `edge`s using the `edge ["<label>"]` syntax. The options for these labels are set to `auto` to offset them. Where TikZ would 'jump the wrong way', a `'` is added after the quoted label to 'swap' the offset e.g. left rather than right.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={auto, text=blue}]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{5}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
  \draw [draw=blue, every edge/.append style={draw=blue, densely dashed, opacity=.5}, fill=magenta]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) coordinate (b) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g) ++(0,0,-\cubez)  -- ++(\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) coordinate (d) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) coordinate (e) edge (g) -- (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- (a) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) coordinate (f) edge (g) -- (d) -- cycle;
  \path [every edge/.append style={draw=blue, |-|}]
    (b) +(0,-5pt) coordinate (b1) edge ["30cm"'] (b1 -| c)
    (b) +(-5pt,0) coordinate (b2) edge ["5cm"] (b2 |- a)
    (c) +(3.5pt,-3.5pt) coordinate (c2) edge ["10cm"'] ([xshift=3.5pt,yshift=-3.5pt]e)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: annotated cuboid]

If you need to draw a group of these or several in different places, defining a `pic` may be a convenient solution. As I've defined it, the `pic` `annotated cuboid` takes a single, optional argument which can set various parameters: `width`, `height`, `depth`, `units` (for the labels) and `scale`. To set colours, fills etc., you can pass an optional argument to the `\pic` to specify `pic actions` e.g. `\pic [draw=red, fill=yellow, text=green] {annotated cuboid={width=10, height=45, depth=89.6, scale=.05, units=mm}};`. Defaults are the current defaults for colours etc., a cuboid 10x10x10, scaled to one tenth natural size, with unit labels in centimetres.

For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {annotated cuboid};
  \pic [fill=magenta, text=blue, draw=blue] at (5,0) {annotated cuboid={width=30, height=5, depth=10}};
  \pic [fill=green, text=green!50!black, draw=green!25!black] at (5,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
  \pic at (1,-3) {annotated cuboid={width=150, height=200, depth=250, scale=.01, units=m}};
  \pic [fill=cyan, text=blue!75!cyan, draw=blue!75!cyan] at (-3,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=15, height=18, depth=13.5, units=}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: annotated cuboids]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  annotated cuboid/.pic={
    \tikzset{%
      every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
      /cuboid/.cd,
      #1
    }
    \draw [every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e) edge (g) -- (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- (a) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f) edge (g) -- (d) -- cycle;
    \path [every edge/.append style={pic actions, |-|}]
    (b) +(0,-5pt) coordinate (b1) edge ["\cubex \cubeunits"'] (b1 -| c)
    (b) +(-5pt,0) coordinate (b2) edge ["\cubey \cubeunits"] (b2 |- a)
    (c) +(3.5pt,-3.5pt) coordinate (c2) edge ["\cubez \cubeunits"'] ([xshift=3.5pt,yshift=-3.5pt]e)
    ;
  },
  /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
  /cuboid/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cubex,
  height/.store in=\cubey,
  depth/.store in=\cubez,
  units/.store in=\cubeunits,
  scale/.store in=\cubescale,
  width=10,
  height=10,
  depth=10,
  units=cm,
  scale=.1,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {annotated cuboid};
  \pic [fill=magenta, text=blue, draw=blue] at (5,0) {annotated cuboid={width=30, height=5, depth=10}};
  \pic [fill=green, text=green!50!black, draw=green!25!black] at (5,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};
  \pic at (1,-3) {annotated cuboid={width=150, height=200, depth=250, scale=.01, units=m}};
  \pic [fill=cyan, text=blue!75!cyan, draw=blue!75!cyan] at (-3,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=15, height=18, depth=13.5, units=}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you position a `\pic` relatively? e.g. `\pic [] (pic-2) at ($ (pic-1) + (5mm,0mm) $)`

Comment: Nevermind, I found my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241719/name-tikz-pic-as-if-it-was-a-node I added `label/.store in=\cubelabel,` So my next thing is centering a node in the shape. Your "center" is the front top right corner. Is there are way to put a node at the center of the shape `\node (\cubelabel) at (whatever) {displayedtext}`? I am not sure what to put in "whatever". Maybe you can help me out here. Something like `at (o -| a)`

Comment: I used `\node [draw,minimum width=\cubescale*\cubex,minimum height=\cubescale*\cubey] (\cubelabel) at ($ (a)!.5!(c) $) {\cubetextlabel};` for the front face, but the scale of the node is not the same as the front face. I am not sure why :(

Comment: @cfr: Great. How to remove the annotation text, I just want to show cube only? Thanks

Comment: @user8264 Just don't add it. You can see where it is set, for goodness sake.

Comment: @user8264 Note that the whole point of this answer was the annotation. Nonetheless, you can just omit it if you don't want it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried with `\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (6,-2)` but it was fail.

Comment: Ask a new question if you need help. Link here for context and include a compilable example (or not compilable, if you get an error). There is better cube code around than mine, though, if you don't need annotations. Shiny ones. Stackable ones.  Rotated ones. Shaded ones. Labelled ones. Mine are about as bog-standard boring as they get.

Comment: @cfr: Thanks. I asked a new question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362190/how-to-draw-connection-between-cube-in-tikz. Hope you can solve it help me