# How to draw connection between cube in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am using tikz to draw multiple cubes. I want to achieve my expected result as bellow

[image]

However, the main difficulty is that locates cube inside and center of the cube and making a connection between them. Currently, I am using manually setting the coordination point. Could you help me to do it?

The online code at https://www.overleaf.com/8937330rhwcmbfhzdvx
This is my modified code based on [how to draw parallelepiped and cube with latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285578/how-to-draw-parallelepiped-and-cube-with-latex/288101?noredirect=1#comment893010_288101)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  annotated cuboid/.pic={
    \tikzset{%
      every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
      /cuboid/.cd,
      #1
    }
    \draw [every edge/.append style={pic actions, densely dashed, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e) edge (g) -- (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- (a) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f) edge (g) -- (d) -- cycle;   
    ;
  },
  /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
  /cuboid/.cd,
  width/.store in=\cubex,
  height/.store in=\cubey,
  depth/.store in=\cubez,
  units/.store in=\cubeunits,
  scale/.store in=\cubescale,
  width=10,
  height=10,
  depth=10,
  units=cm,
  scale=.1,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,-2.7) {annotated cuboid={width=2, height=4, depth=3, units=m}};


\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (5,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}}; 

\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4.8,-2.7) {annotated cuboid={width=2, height=2, depth=2, units=m}};

\pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (5.5,-2.3) {annotated cuboid={width=3, height=10, depth=7, units=m}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is good, you just need to label your coordinates for each cuboid, which do can do by adding a `label` to your pics. Once you have done this then you can draw between the vertices with draw commands like `\draw (e-B) -- (a-D);`.

**EDIT**
You can make all of the lines of the cuboids dashed in a similar way: add a `line`  argument to your `annotated cuboid` that defaults to `draw` and then set `line=dashed` when you want all of the lines to be dashed lines. Similarly, I have added a `\cubeback` that can be used to remove the dashed lines at the "back" of the cubes, as in the orange cube below.

I have coloured your cubes to make it clearer (to me), which cuboid is which:

[image]

Here is the full modified MWE:

```
  \documentclass[border=5pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
  \tikzset{
    annotated cuboid/.pic={
      \tikzset{%
        every edge quotes/.append style={midway, auto},
        /cuboid/.cd,
        #1
      }
      \draw [\cubeline,every edge/.append style={pic actions, \cubeback, opacity=.5}, pic actions]
      (0,0,0) coordinate (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(-\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (b-\cubelabel) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g-\cubelabel) ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez)  -- ++(\cubescale*\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (d-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,-\cubescale*\cubey,0) coordinate (e-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (c-\cubelabel) -- cycle
      (o-\cubelabel) -- (a-\cubelabel) -- ++(0,0,-\cubescale*\cubez) coordinate (f-\cubelabel) edge (g-\cubelabel) -- (d-\cubelabel) -- cycle;
      ;
    },
    /cuboid/.search also={/tikz},
    /cuboid/.cd,
    width/.store in=\cubex,
    height/.store in=\cubey,
    depth/.store in=\cubez,
    units/.store in=\cubeunits,
    scale/.store in=\cubescale,
    label/.store in=\cubelabel,
    line/.store in=\cubeline,
    backline/.store in=\cubeback,
    width=10,
    height=10,
    depth=10,
    units=cm,
    scale=.1,
    line=draw,
    backline=densely dashed,
  }
  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \pic [fill=gray!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,-2) {annotated cuboid={label=A, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=red!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4,-2.7) {annotated cuboid={label=B, width=2, height=4, depth=3, units=m, line=dashed}};

  \pic [fill=blue!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (5,-2) {annotated cuboid={label=C, width=6, height=20, depth=15, units=mm}};

  \pic [fill=green!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (4.8,-2.7) {annotated cuboid={label=D, width=2, height=2, depth=2, units=m, line=dashed}};

  \pic [fill=orange!20, text=green!50!black, draw=black] at (5.5,-2.3) {annotated cuboid={label=E, width=3, height=10, depth=7, units=m, backline=draw}};

  \draw (e-B) -- (a-D);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

So all that I have done is added a `label` to your `annotated cuboid`, which gets stored in `\cubelabel`m and changed your coordinates ub the cuboid code to`(o),(a),...,(g)` to `(o-\cubelabel),...,(g-\cubelabel)`. Then the `annotated cuboid` commnds are called with `label=*` and the `\draw` commands work.

Comment: Great. How to make the line of inside cube is the dash line

Comment: @user8264 I've updated the code to add another argument, `line`, that sets the "line style". Adding `line=dashed` will make the lines of the cuboid dashed lines, `line=dotted` will make dotted line etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. I want to ask one more thing. In the case of `pic` definition. If I want to remove the dash line in the cube. Do I need to make a new pic or just add one more argument

Comment: By "remove the dash line" do mean the dashed lines at the back of the cubes? If so, then this is done by the `densely dashed` in the `every edge` command. You change these lines using a variable like `\cubeline` that defaults to `draw` (or `densely dashed` etc).

Comment: Yes. I want to remove this dashed line in some cube. Not all cube. It means that some cube has dashed line at the back but some cube has no dashed line. So, I think it is better to make it as one argument. Can you help me to edit your code?

Comment: @user8264 Just add another argument, say `backline`. You will need `backline/.store in=\cubebline` and `\cubbline=densely dashed` in the `/cuboid/.cd` block and then replace `densely dashed` with `\cubebline` in `append style` command. Finally, to use it write`annotated cuboid={backline=draw, ...}` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I added it at https://www.overleaf.com/8937330rhwcmbfhzdvx. However, it cannot remove the dashed line in the back cube.

Comment: @user8264 See my edit to remove the dashed line. The dashed line is now missing from the orange cube.

Comment: Thank Andrew. But I want to remove it. It means the line will be invisible as my figure in the question. Currently, it appears as a line in back. Let see the online result at https://www.overleaf.com/8937330rhwcmbfhzdvx

Comment: To remove the line set `backline` equal to the fill colour. For example, `backline=orange!20` will completely remove the lines from the orange cube. Sorry, I misunderstood and thought by "remove" you meant "remove the dashes" rather than "remove the line". Silly of me! (Btw, overleaf is pretty cool!)

Comment: @Andrew, +1 for your precious work.