# Refactor cuboid diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have combined portions of code from two other threads to create a cuboid diagram. Works well but I want to show the lines connecting the cuboids in a more '3D' way. Some lines are now overlapping. Moreover I will connect some more components on either sides of the cuboids. Don't know how to make a proper 3D connections.

Not a real tikz programmer. So I just read and combine code.Cuboid is from [Tom Bombadil](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69588/tikz-realistic-3d-grid/69880#69880)

```
\newif\ifcuboidshade
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{carolinablue}{rgb}{0.6, 0.73, 0.89}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{languidlavender}{rgb}{0.84, 0.79, 0.87}
\definecolor{tan}{rgb}{0.82, 0.71, 0.55}
\definecolor{tearose(rose)}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{wisteria}{rgb}{0.79, 0.63, 0.86}
\definecolor{skymagenta}{rgb}{0.81, 0.44, 0.69}

\tikzset{
  laser beam action/.style={
    line width=\pgflinewidth+.1pt,draw opacity=.1,draw=#1,
  },
  laser beam recurs/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\level}{#1-1}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\level}{0}}%
    {\tikzset{preaction={laser beam action=#2}}}%
    {\tikzset{preaction={laser beam action=#2,laser beam recurs={\level}{#2}}}}
  },
  laser beam/.style={preaction={laser beam recurs={10}{#1}},draw opacity=1,draw=#1},
}

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shiftx/.initial=0,
  shifty/.initial=0,
  dimx/.initial=3,
  dimy/.initial=3,
  dimz/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  densityx/.initial=1,
  densityy/.initial=1,
  densityz/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  anglex/.initial=0,
  angley/.initial=90,
  anglez/.initial=225,
  scalex/.initial=0.3,
  scaley/.initial=0.3,
  scalez/.initial=0.3,
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=babyblue},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=babyblue},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=babyblue},
  shade/.is if=cuboidshade,
  shadecolordark/.initial=black,
  shadecolorlight/.initial=white,
  shadeopacity/.initial=0.15,
  shadesamples/.initial=16,
  emphedge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emphstyle/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shiftx}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shifty}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityx}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityy}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityz}}
  \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimx}}
  \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimy}}
  \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimz}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimx}{1}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,...,\dimx}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}}
  {     \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimy}{1}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,...,\dimy}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;
    }
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimx}{1}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,...,\dimx}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}}
  { \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimz}{1}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,...,\dimz}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimy}{1}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,...,\dimy}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}}
  { \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimz}{1}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,...,\dimz}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
    }
  }
  \ifcuboidemphedge
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi

    \ifcuboidshade
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepx}{\dimx/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepy}{\dimy/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepz}{\dimz/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lows}{\s-1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cpercent}{(\lows)/(\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}-1)*100}
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (0,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (0,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (\dimx,0,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,0,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
    }
    \fi 

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother

\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=20,dimz=30,shiftx=100};

\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=150,,shifty=-99,front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white},top/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white},right/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white}};

\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=180,,shifty=-69,front/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!white,fill=wisteria!25!white},top/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!skymagenta,fill=wisteria!25!white},right/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!skymagenta,fill=wisteria!25!white}};

\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-2.61,-0.396) -- (4.7,-3.2);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-2.61,-1.3) -- (4.7,-4.1);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-1.91,-0.7) -- (5.6,-3.5);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-1.9,0.2) -- (5.2,-2.6);

\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=-63.54,shifty=-19.37,front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white},top/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white},right/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white}};
```

Update : I think naming the edges of the cube will be the first step as the lines will be more standardized then. Let me try.

Comment: It would be nice if you could reveal the sources of the code and promote your snippet to an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: MWE ? You mean I code a sample ? One effect I found is https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362190/how-to-draw-connection-between-cube-in-tikz

Comment: I want you to provide a compilable code, not just fragments, like my code below and also to explain what you want to achieve, possibly with a screenshot of some desired output. I had to look up the sources of your fragments to produce a compilable code, and to give credit to those who wrote these nice codes.

Comment: RIght. I use tikz editor which uses the preamble. Not portable.I think. Works in the editor though.

Comment: What if Tom Bombadil provided you with a "non-portable" code, i.e. something that does not compile on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw things in the right order.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{carolinablue}{rgb}{0.6, 0.73, 0.89}
\definecolor{ceruleanblue}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}
\definecolor{languidlavender}{rgb}{0.84, 0.79, 0.87}
\definecolor{tan}{rgb}{0.82, 0.71, 0.55}
\definecolor{tearose(rose)}{rgb}{0.96, 0.76, 0.76}
\definecolor{wisteria}{rgb}{0.79, 0.63, 0.86}
\definecolor{skymagenta}{rgb}{0.81, 0.44, 0.69}

% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29882/121799
% and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387530/121799
%-------------------
\newif\ifcuboidshade
\newif\ifcuboidemphedge

\tikzset{
  cuboid/.is family,
  cuboid,
  shiftx/.initial=0,
  shifty/.initial=0,
  dimx/.initial=3,
  dimy/.initial=3,
  dimz/.initial=3,
  scale/.initial=1,
  densityx/.initial=1,
  densityy/.initial=1,
  densityz/.initial=1,
  rotation/.initial=0,
  anglex/.initial=0,
  angley/.initial=90,
  anglez/.initial=225,
  scalex/.initial=1,
  scaley/.initial=1,
  scalez/.initial=0.5,
  front/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  top/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  right/.style={draw=black,fill=white},
  shade/.is if=cuboidshade,
  shadecolordark/.initial=black,
  shadecolorlight/.initial=white,
  shadeopacity/.initial=0.15,
  shadesamples/.initial=16,
  emphedge/.is if=cuboidemphedge,
  emphstyle/.style={thick},
}

\newcommand{\tikzcuboidkey}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cuboid/#1}}

% Commands
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[1]{
    \tikzset{cuboid,#1} % Process Keys passed to command
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorxy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalex}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglex})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectoryy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scaley}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{angley})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzx}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*cos(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\vectorzy}{\tikzcuboidkey{scalez}*sin(\tikzcuboidkey{anglez})*28.452756}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shiftx}, yshift=\tikzcuboidkey{shifty}, scale=\tikzcuboidkey{scale}, rotate=\tikzcuboidkey{rotation}, x={(\vectorxx,\vectorxy)}, y={(\vectoryx,\vectoryy)}, z={(\vectorzx,\vectorzy)}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingx}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityx}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingy}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityy}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\steppingz}{1/\tikzcuboidkey{densityz}}
  \newcommand{\dimx}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimx}}
  \newcommand{\dimy}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimy}}
  \newcommand{\dimz}{\tikzcuboidkey{dimz}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondx}{2*\steppingx}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondy}{2*\steppingy}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\secondz}{2*\steppingz}
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimx}{1}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,...,\dimx}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}}
  {     \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimy}{1}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,...,\dimy}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/front] (\lowx,\lowy,\dimz) -- (\lowx,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\y,\dimz) -- (\x,\lowy,\dimz) -- cycle;
    }
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimx}{1}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,...,\dimx}}
    {\foreach \x in {\steppingx,\secondx,...,\dimx}}
  { \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimz}{1}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,...,\dimz}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowx}{(\x-\steppingx)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/top] (\lowx,\dimy,\lowz) -- (\lowx,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\z) -- (\x,\dimy,\lowz) -- cycle;
        }
    }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimy}{1}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,...,\dimy}}
    {\foreach \y in {\steppingy,\secondy,...,\dimy}}
  { \ifthenelse{\equal{\dimz}{1}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,...,\dimz}}
    {\foreach \z in {\steppingz,\secondz,...,\dimz}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowy}{(\y-\steppingy)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\lowz}{(\z-\steppingz)}
      \filldraw[cuboid/right] (\dimx,\lowy,\lowz) -- (\dimx,\lowy,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\z) -- (\dimx,\y,\lowz) -- cycle;
    }
  }
  \ifcuboidemphedge
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- cycle;%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (0,\dimy,\dimz) -- (0,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz) -- (\dimx,\dimy,\dimz);%
    \draw[cuboid/emphstyle] (\dimx,\dimy,0) -- (\dimx,0,0) -- (\dimx,0,\dimz);%
    \fi

    \ifcuboidshade
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepx}{\dimx/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepy}{\dimy/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\cstepz}{\dimz/\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}}
    {   \pgfmathsetmacro{\lows}{\s-1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\cpercent}{(\lows)/(\tikzcuboidkey{shadesamples}-1)*100}
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\s*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (\s*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,0,\dimz) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- (0,\lows*\cstepy,\dimz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (0,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\s*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,0) -- (\lows*\cstepx,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (0,\dimy,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
        \fill[opacity=\tikzcuboidkey{shadeopacity},color=\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolorlight}!\cpercent!\tikzcuboidkey{shadecolordark}] (\dimx,0,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,\s*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,\s*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,0) -- (\dimx,\lows*\cstepy,\lows*\cstepz) -- (\dimx,0,\lows*\cstepz) -- cycle;
    }
    \fi 

  \end{scope}
}

\makeatother
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80207/121799
\tikzset{
  laser beam action/.style={
    line width=\pgflinewidth+.2pt,draw opacity=.1,draw=#1,
  },
  laser beam recurs/.code 2 args={%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\level}{#1-1}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\level}{0}}%
    {\tikzset{preaction={laser beam action=#2}}}%
    {\tikzset{preaction={laser beam action=#2,laser beam recurs={\level}{#2}}}}
  },
  laser beam/.style={preaction={laser beam recurs={10}{#1}},draw opacity=1,draw=#1},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=20,dimz=30,shiftx=100,shade,shadeopacity=0.35};
\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=-63.54,shifty=-19.37,front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white},top/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white},right/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=tan!25!white},shade,%
shadeopacity=0.35};
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-2.61,-0.396) -- (4.7,-3.2);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-2.61,-1.3) -- (4.7,-4.1);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-1.91,-0.7) -- (5.6,-3.5);
\path[laser beam=ceruleanblue] (-1.9,0.2) -- (5.2,-2.6);
\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=150,,shifty=-99,front/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white},top/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white},right/.style={draw=blue!75!black,fill=languidlavender!25!white},
shade,shadeopacity=0.35};
\tikzcuboid{dimx=1,dimy=3,dimz=3,shiftx=180,,shifty=-69,front/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!white,fill=wisteria!25!white},top/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!skymagenta,fill=wisteria!25!white},right/.style={draw=skymagenta!75!skymagenta,fill=wisteria!25!white},
shade,shadeopacity=0.35};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You mean I shift. I understand that. But Just the annotations and transparency are missing. I think.