# How to draw this 3d perspective diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pic  at (2,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=mm}};
  \pic at (-0.5,-2.3) {annotated cuboid={width=50, height=36, depth=12, units=mm}};
  \pic [fill=green!60!black, text=green!75!black, draw=blue!75!green] at (-8,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=}};
  \node (A) at (-8,-8) {Espace réel};
   \node (b) at (3,-8) {Espace perçu};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-2.6) {\footnotesize Facteurs culturels};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.2) {Facteurs psychologiques};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.8) {Facteurs sociaux};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-4.4) {Facteurs économiques};
     \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-2.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-3.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Tactile};
         \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-3.2) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-6.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Auditif};
           \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-9.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Olfactif};
            \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-12.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Gustatif};
             \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-5.4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-15.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Visuel};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pic  at (2,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=mm}};
  \pic at (-0.5,-2.3) {annotated cuboid={width=50, height=36, depth=12, units=mm}};
  \pic [fill=green!60!black, text=green!75!black, draw=blue!75!green] at (-8,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=}};
  \node (A) at (-8,-8) {Espace réel};
   \node (b) at (3,-8) {Espace perçu};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-2.6) {\footnotesize Facteurs culturels};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.2) {Facteurs psychologiques};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.8) {Facteurs sociaux};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-4.4) {Facteurs économiques};
     \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-2.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-3.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Tactile};
         \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-3.2) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-6.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Auditif};
           \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-9.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Olfactif};
            \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-12.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Gustatif};
             \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-5.4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-15.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Visuel};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1]{images/bailly.png}
\caption{Percpetion de l'espace urbain}
\label{fig:bailly}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \pic  at (2,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=mm}};
  \pic at (-0.5,-2.3) {annotated cuboid={width=50, height=36, depth=12, units=mm}};
  \pic [fill=green!60!black, text=green!75!black, draw=blue!75!green] at (-8,-2) {annotated cuboid={width=4, height=50, depth=30, units=}};
  \node (A) at (-8,-8) {Espace réel};
   \node (b) at (3,-8) {Espace perçu};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-2.6) {\footnotesize Facteurs culturels};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.2) {Facteurs psychologiques};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-3.8) {Facteurs sociaux};
     \node (c) at(-2.8,-4.4) {Facteurs économiques};
     \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-2.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-3.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Tactile};
         \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-3.2) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-6.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Auditif};
           \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-9.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Olfactif};
            \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-4.6) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-12.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Gustatif};
             \draw[->,black] (-7.8,-5.4) -- ( $ (a)!.25!(2.9,-15.9) $ ) node [midway, sloped, above] {Visuel};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: graph]

Comment: The questions says you try, but you don't show what you've tried in the question. May be it would be simpler if you explained what is it that you can't exactly do. Arrows and text seems quite simple in TikZ and other programs, so I imagine that's not the problem.

Comment: I use this code: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285578/how-to-draw-parallelepiped-and-cube-with-latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: Ok thnks, I will try to do it myself

Comment: Any updates here? Your preamble is still missing. It has to  be compilable code. Please reference your code, if its [stolen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30316/124842).