# How to denote point with letter in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make a line, like this one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage(tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw (0,0) -- (1,0.5)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For example, I draw a line that starts from coordinate (0,0) to (1,0.5). It should be like this one.

[image]

(Note: This is a picture that I draw in Paint)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to denote the points (for example A is the coordinate of (0,0) and B is the coordinate of (1,0.5).).

Another example, I copied one of the codes in this link:
[How to draw parallelepiped and cube with LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285578/how-to-draw-parallelepiped-and-cube-with-latex/288101#288101), and then I replace it as

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every edge quotes/.append style={auto, text=black}]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
  \draw [draw=, every edge/.append style={draw=black, densely dashed, opacity=.5}, fill=white]
    (0,0,0) coordinate (o) -- ++(-\cubex,0,0) coordinate (a) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) coordinate (b) edge coordinate [pos=1] (g) ++(0,0,-\cubez)  -- ++(\cubex,0,0) coordinate (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) coordinate (d) -- ++(0,-\cubey,0) coordinate (e) edge (g) -- (c) -- cycle
    (o) -- (a) -- ++(0,0,-\cubez) coordinate (f) edge (g) -- (d) -- cycle;
  \path [every edge/.append style={draw=black, |-|}]
    (b) +(0,-5pt) coordinate (b1) edge ["8cm"'] (b1 -| c)
    (b) +(-5pt,0) coordinate (b2) edge ["8cm"] (b2 |- a)
    (c) +(3.5pt,-3.5pt) coordinate (c2) edge ["8cm"'] ([xshift=3.5pt,yshift=-3.5pt]e)
```

And I don't know how to denote point (for example let ABCDEFGH be a cube).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Just add nodes above given coordinates:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141593]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) node[above] {A} -- (2,1) node[above] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Addendum:**

- You are quite demanding: full service for two equal problems.
- At the cube the adding of labels is the same problem as it is already solved for the line, in the answer above. So you only need to add labels to coordinates accordingly
- However, your code for the cube is erroneous, so I guess that this is your main problem at it.
- Since you are novice, I made exception and clean-up your code for cube and add desired labels for all corners (next time your question probably will be closed as *Needs details or clarity*).
- Please, always provide complete small document called MWE (Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem and not only uncomplete code fragment. Many times problems has source in MWE preamble.
- And finally, please one problem per question.

MWE for the cube can be for example:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141593]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every edge quotes/.style={auto, font=\footnotesize, sloped, inner sep=2pt},
every label/.style = {inner sep=1pt, font=\scriptsize}
                        ]
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubex}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubey}{3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\cubez}{3}
  \draw 
    (0,0,0) coordinate[label=below left:A] (a) 
    -- ++ ( \cubex,0,0) coordinate[label=below right:B] (b) 
    -- ++ (0, \cubey,0) coordinate[label=above  left:C] (c) 
    -- ++ (-\cubex,0,0) coordinate[label=above  left:D] (d)
    -- cycle
    (d) -- ++ (0,0,-\cubez) coordinate[label=above right:E] (e) 
        -- ++ ( \cubex,0,0) coordinate[label=above right:F] (f) 
        -- ++ (0,-\cubey,0) coordinate[label=above right:G] (g) 
        -- (b)
    (c) -- (f);
  \fill[red!30, semitransparent] (a) -- (d) -- (e) -- (f) -- (g) -- (b) -- cycle;
  \draw[densely dashed] 
    (a) -- (e |- g) coordinate[label=above right:H] (h) -- (g)
           (h) -- (e);
  \path[draw=cyan, |-|]
    ([yshift=-3mm] a) edge ["\qty{8}{cm}"'] ([yshift=-3mm] b)
    ([xshift=-3mm] a) edge ["\qty{8}{cm}" ] ([xshift=-3mm] d)
    ([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}] b) to ["\qty{8}{cm}"'] ([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}] g)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

**Edit:** Added is `siunitx` package and lenght is written as `\qty{8}{cm}`.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64Npi.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NlAR.png

Comment: What about the codes to make a cube?

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr one problem for question please! BTW, second code is quite erroneous, to clean up it, I need more time.

Comment: Well. I appreciate your work. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I don't know how to use `\path`. Is there a link for further information?

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr, please read "Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual". It is part of your package installation. You can also find on CTAN (use Google). Documentation is huge, but for start should be sufficient to read first tutorial and than part III: "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm". Also can be helpful "Minimal introduction to TikZ (unofficial)" which you can find on CTAN too.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: +1 and haha for `You are quite demanding` :)

Comment: I have a question here. For command `\path`, how do I use the line (like the previous problem) from A to B? Maybe if you give some advice, I'd like to practice it to draw two-dimensional shapes using the command `\path` for measuring.

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr, sorry, t don't undestand you, what is the problem. IN answer you have examples has to use `path` as well `\draw` command. A latter is actually abrevation for `\path[draw] `. See  section "11.3 Actions on Paths", page 125 in Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual for Version 3.1.9a.

Comment: @Dedhert.Jr, you may explore https://texample.net/. There  are many examples of the use of Ti*k*Z.