# Connect different newcommands made with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I'm starting to manipulate `\newcommand`, so far everything is okay except for connecting two commands made with tikz. As shown on the picture below, there's a gap between the lines. How to fix that ?

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\motor}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [circle,draw,inner sep=0.5cm] at (0,0) (a) {M};
\draw (a.north) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (m1) {\motor};
\node at (4,0) (m2) {\motor};
\draw (m1.east) -- (m2.west);
\draw [red] (m1.north) -- (0,2) -- (4,2) -- (m2.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do not nest `tikzpictures`... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul. Better learn how to use `pic`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241719/name-tikz-pic-as-if-it-was-a-node

Comment: BTW, just adding at the top of your code `\documentclass{article}` makes it a quite nice [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [never nest `tikzpictures`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul)...

If you want to use macros, it is **much** better to put in the macro part of the path (and using relative coordinates, so that you can move it around):

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\motor}[1]{
node [circle,draw,inner sep=0.5cm](#1) {M} (#1.north) -- ++(0,1.5) 
     coordinate (#1-top);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) \motor{m1};
\draw (4,0) \motor{m2};
\draw (m1.east) -- (m2.west);
\draw [red] (m1-top) -- ++(0,2) -| (m2-top);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise, you can learn how to use `pic`s: [Name tikz pic as if it was a node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241719/name-tikz-pic-as-if-it-was-a-node)

Comment: It's more clear for me now. A question, (may be a disappointing one) , what the commands `++` and `-|` mean ?

Comment: `++` is to use a relative coordinate, and `-|` is draw a line first horizontally then vertically. You should really read (and do) at least the first tutorial in the Ti*k*Z manual...

Comment: Roger that, thank you!