# How to access style values of a node

Tags: tikz-styles

I'd like to access the style of a node, something like `mynode.fill` or `mynode.color` etc.. Particularly, I have this task: draw a node and grid it. But I'd like to use some node properties when I plot the grid.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,shapes.geometric,arrows,calc}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\gridnode}[3]{\draw[color=#3, step=#2] (#1.south east)  grid (#1.north west);}
\newcommand{\gridinnode}[3]{\tikz{\draw[color=#3, step=#2] (#1.south east)  grid (#1.north west);}}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[draw=none, fill=white] (-4cm, -2cm) rectangle (4cm, 2cm);

\node[rectangle, color=red, inner sep=0, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=3cm, fill=black!20] (mynode) at (0, 0)
{
    % Anything like this one that works would be neat!  
    %\gridinnode{mynode}{1cm}{red};
};

% Can I access the color of mynode by using mynode instead of passing in this value?
% BTW: how to align the grid with the node? I don't like to do a lot of calculation. 
\gridnode{mynode}{1cm}{red};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your approach nests `tikzpicture`s, which really should be avoided. I think you want to use a `local bounding box`, or `fit` the stuff. The fill color is stored in `\tikz@fillcolor`, and if you fill `\tikz@mode@filltrue` is also issued.

Comment: Retrieving option value is in general hard. You need to know the implementation of every key and take care of the grouping/scoping. The `tikz` way is to define a style key `my nodes/.style={color=red, ...}` and then you can apply it to different nodes. For the positioning problem, you might find [`pgfmanual`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 3.4 and 3.8 helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Eventually, I solved the problem with pic. I think my problem question is really about how to turn a grid into a node. Pic seems to be the best choice with my limited skills in tikz.

Comment: This is the key technique I have used: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241719/name-tikz-pic-as-if-it-was-a-node