# Define a pic and use it as node

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-styles, nodes, tikz-pic

My purpose is draw an *horizontal* cylinder. I defined the left and the right base with `/.pic` . Now I would link these bases with `\draw`, using the bases anchor point `.north` and `.south`.
Something goes wrong: no output

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            leftbase/.pic={
                code={       
                    \def\xR{0.5cm}; %x radius of ellipse
                    \def\yR{1cm};  %y radius of ellipse                 
                    \draw (-\xR,0) arc(90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
                    \draw (-\xR,0) arc(90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
                }
            },
            rightbase/.pic={
                code={       
                    \def\xR{0.5cm}; %x radius of ellipse
                    \def\yR{1cm};  %y radius of ellipse                 
                    \draw[dotted] (-\xR+1.7in,0) arc(90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
                    \draw         (-\xR+1.7in,0) arc(90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
                }
            }
        }
    node[leftbase] (lb) {};
    node[rightbase] (rb) {};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Will it change, when you draw the nodes which represent the pics?

Comment: Yes, it change with \pic{leftbase} and \pic{rightbase}

Comment: Drawing the pics?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/16bZFXa.jpg

Comment: Caution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/241719/47927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you're not using `pic` correctly.
Here a slight change that makes your code work:

[image: pic as a node (quite)]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{
            leftbase/.pic={
                code={       
                    \def\xR{0.5cm}; %x radius of ellipse
                    \def\yR{1cm};  %y radius of ellipse                 
                    \draw (-\xR,0) arc(90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
                    \draw (-\xR,0) arc(90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
                }
            },
            rightbase/.pic={
                code={       
                    \def\xR{0.5cm}; %x radius of ellipse
                    \def\yR{1cm};  %y radius of ellipse                 
                    \draw[dotted] (-\xR+1.7in,0) arc(90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
                    \draw         (-\xR+1.7in,0) arc(90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
                }
            }
        }
        \pic [local bounding box=lb] at (0,0) {leftbase};
        \pic [local bounding box=rb] at (1,0) {rightbase};
        \draw (lb.north) -- (rb.north);
        \draw (lb.south) -- (rb.south);  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```